# MySQL Many-Many Table Primary Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, indexing, many-to-many

I'm using a many-many table to reference professors to lectures.  Each lecture could have multiple professors, each professor could have multiple lectures.  However, I need to be able to access this data from both directions (by joining professors table to lectures, and vice versa).  In MySQL, composite key indices only work when the first column in the composite key matches the first column in the WHERE clause.

Long story short: is there any way to use the index regardless of the direction I'm mapping?  Or do I just need to define a PRIMARY on (professor_id, lecture_id) and then an INDEX on each column individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add primary key on `professor_id, lecture_id` and regular index on one field `lecture_id`.

It is enough.